# Get average words per file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

If i have a folder of text files, how can I get the average words per file using Bash commands?

I know that I can use `wc -w` to get words per file, but i'm unsure of how to get the total number of words across all files, and then divide that number by the number of text files

Comment: `wc -w * | grep total` will get you started... Not sure where to go from there. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This recursively traverses the filesystem and counts all words and files. In the end it divides the total number of words by the number of files:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | awk '{numfiles=numfiles+1;total += $1} END{print total/numfiles}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get total word count by:

```
cat *.txt | wc -w
```

and file number by:

```
ls *.txt | wc -l
```

Then you can devide them.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a piece of advice. You might use [Loops](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html) and [Variable Assignment](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html).

Answer (score 0):

Huang's solution is very good, but will emit errors on any directories.  And division is a bit of a pain, since all arithmetic in the shell is with integers.  Here's a script that does what you want:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *; do
    test -f "$file" || continue
    c=$( wc -w "$file" | awk '{print $1}' )
    : $(( total += $c ))
    : $(( count += 1 ))
done

echo $total $count 10k / p | dc | sed 's/0*$//'
```

But bunting's awk solution is the way to go.